# How list all windows Code Page Identifiers in DelphiXE7?

Tags: delphi

I need to list all the windows Code Pages in a combo box for selection.
This will be used to set the application code page.
How can we list all Windows **Code Page Identifiers** in *DelphiXE7*?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.delphipraxis.net/727316-post10.html) helps.

Comment: EnumSystemCodePages can be used to fetch all the code pages

Answer (score 3):

```
var
  CPList: TStrings;

function CodePagesProc(CodePageString: PChar): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  CPList.Add(CodePageString);
  Result := TRUE;
end;

procedure TFrmX.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  CPList := ComboBox1.Items;
  CPList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    EnumSystemCodePages(@CodePagesProc, CP_SUPPORTED); 
    // EnumSystemCodePages will call CodePagesProc() repeatedly for each code page.
  finally
    CPList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Reference:

[EnumSystemCodePages function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317825(VS.85).aspx)

http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.asp?ArtID=604277

http://www.delphipraxis.net/727316-post10.html